# How do I correctly call the $_SESSION variable in PHP?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am trying to call the `$_SESSION` `username` variable so that It will show in a URL like

```
/users/USERNAME/
```

I know there's a way to do this, but I must be doing it wrong because here's the error I get: Parse error: syntax error,

```
unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or 
T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

What am I doing wrong to get this, and how can I fix it?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['md']['tmp_name'], 
"users/'.$_SESSION['username'].".$_FILES['md']['name'] );
```

Comment: Perhaps you should first read the documentation? ;) and don't mix the "

Comment: Any decent editor will have syntax highlighting that should make the issue obvious.  When what should be PHP code is highlighted as a string (as Markdown did *while you were posting the question*), that oughta be a clue that your quotes are messed up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong mixing of `"` and `'` and one `"` missing

```
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['md']['tmp_name'], "users/".$_SESSION['username']."/".$_FILES['md']['name'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a parse error.

```
"users/"
```

not

```
"users/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your string before concatenation.

```
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['md']['tmp_name'], "users/" . $_SESSION['username'] . $_FILES['md']['name'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug in code, try this

```
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['md']['tmp_name'],"users/".$_SESSION['username'].$_FILES['md']['name'] );
```

or

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['md']['tmp_name'],"users/".$_SESSION['username']."/".$_FILES['md']['name'] );
```